# How to refresh all queries when data in named table is changed using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to use VBA to refresh queries. The following code works while I refer to specified column. However I would like to specify the changing data to named table.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 4 Then ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

I tried:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select
```

but it dosen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then 
        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If

End Sub
```